# How to remove children of TextBlock form specific child?

Tags: wpf, textblock, removechild

Assuming I have a `TextBlock` like below. At runtime I want remove/delete all its children from the first `LineBreak` onward (include `LineBreak`), keep the before. How I can do it? Thank!

```
<TextBlock Name="tbl">
    <Run/>
    ....
    <Run/>
    <LineBreak/>
    <Run/>
    ....
    <Run/>
</TextBlock>
```

I did this and error :)

```
    bool begin = false;

    foreach (var item in tbl.Inlines)
    {
        if (item is LineBreak) begin = true;
        if (begin) tbl.Inlines.Remove(item);
    }
```

Comment: I just saw your edit .. 
what was the error ?

Comment: @eranotzap: When I remove an item, the tbl.Inlines also change, that is error

Comment: Then use a For get the count pre hand  , and iterate it with a for loop like i have , you can't just a collection when using it's enumerator  
(calling For each for example )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   List<Inline> _inlinesToRemove = new List<Inline>();      
   bool lineBreakFound = false;
   for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(textBlock); i++)
   {
       Inline _inline = (Inline)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(textBlock, i);

       if (_inline is LineBreak)
       {
           lineBreakFound = true;
           _inlinesToRemove.Add(_inline); // remove the line break as well 
       }
       // not use else here
       if (lineBreakFound)
       {
            _inlinesToRemove.Add(_inline);
       }
   }

   foreach( Inline _inline in _inlinesToRemove)
   { 
       textBlock.Inlines.Remove(_inline );
   }
```

Comment: Sorry my edit is wrong. You already added the LineBreak to list before, then use else is true. Please reverse it.